# Dealing with IReadOnlyCollection property in EfCore 2.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got the following domain entity:

```
public string Reference { get; private set; }
public int SupplierId { get; private set; }
public int BranchId { get; private set; }
public Guid CreatedBy { get; private set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; private set; }
public Source Source { get; private set; }
public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; private set; }
public decimal NetTotal { get; private set; }
public decimal GrossTotal { get; private set; }

private List<PurchaseOrderLineItem> _lineItems = new List<PurchaseOrderLineItem>();
public IReadOnlyCollection<PurchaseOrderLineItem> LineItems => _lineItems.AsReadOnly();
```

I have the following configuration for the line items:

```
builder.Property(x => x.LineItems)
       .HasField("_lineItems")
       .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

However, when I run my app I'm getting the following error:

```
The property 'PurchaseOrder.LineItems' is of type 'IReadOnlyCollection<PurchaseOrderLineItem>' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

My understanding is that EF should only be using the backing field per my configuration?

I have tried adding the [NotMapped] attribute just to see what happened, but that didn't work.

Am I really wrong with this? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to configure a backing field usage for a navigation property, but not via `Property` method which is for primitive property, and not via fluent API (doesn't exist at this time), but directly through mutable model metadata associated with the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>()
    .HasMany(e => e.LineItems)
    .WithOne(e => e.PurchaseOrder) // or `WithOne() in case there is no inverse navigation property
    .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field); // <--
```

You can also set the mode for all entity navigation properties (you can still override it for individual properties) by using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>()
    .Metadata.SetNavigationAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Comment: Good to know. I don't know that we can by doing like this. Anyway after re-reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field#conventions) I think also you don't need this because by conventions _listItems will be used automattically as backing field so. 

So my question is => what if the backing field does not respect the convention?

Comment: @CodeNotFound If it doesn't, then there is also `SetField` method.